# Global XAML construct

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need a bar (Buttons, Images) on top of my window. I have 5 different windows. In 3 of them I want to add the bar. Instead of changing my 3 XAML files by a change I want just have a one place. How I can achieve this?

My "Bar" construct:

```
<StackPanel>
  <Button></Button>
  ...
</StackPanel>
```

XAML file:

```
<Window>
  <Grid>

    ...

    <!-- add here my "Bar" construct -->

    ...

  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you would typically use a `UserControl`for. Create a `UserControl` named something like "MyBarControl" and move the `StackPanel` that defines the actual bar there:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button></Button>
        ...
    </StackPanel>
```

Then Insert the `UserControl` as an element in the window where you want to display the bar:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>

        ...

        <!-- add here my "Bar" construct -->
        <local:MyBarControl />
        ...

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Using this approach you can reuse the same `UserControl` in several different windows and other views.